# Optimal way to load header/footer file template in another file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to find the best solution to load an `HTML` template header/footer file into another (like home, contact info...). I'm using `HTML5` but if `PHP` is the best way I can convert it to PHP using `PHP Include.`

For now i'm using `load()` jquery function in, for example, index.html file:

```
    $(function(){
$("header").load("http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/generic-html/header.html")
$("footer").load("http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/generic-html/footer.html")
});
```

The problem is that if I have an `script` in `index.html` file calling a `class` on the `header.html` or `footer.html`, the `script` **can't found it**, only if the `class` or `id` **is in the same document that the script.** That's why I'm searching the best way to do it, fixing this thing too.

Comment: I would recommend that you look into using some template engine (in PHP) like Twig, Plates or similar. Then you can create layouts and easily create reusable partials etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle after the data is loaded from header.html and footer.html.
Do it in [callback complete](http://api.jquery.com/load/) like this:

```
<script>
$("header").load("http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/generic-html/header.html",function( ) {
  //loaded html here
  // you can start to do magic with the header.html elements here.
})

$("footer").load("http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/generic-html/footer.html",function( ) {
  // loaded html here
  // you can start to do magic with the footer.html elements here.
})
</script>
```

But this is not a best solution, you should render the template in server-side to avoid network/browser issues with the javascript and better for SEO.

Comment: So you recommend to use php templates like PHPPlates? Or what you mean with "render the template in backend"

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga Yes, I recommend to use some php templates like PHPPlates, it's server side rendering.

Comment: What do you think about PHP include?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a need of backand language then use PHP, but if not then you can use any js library or framework like React or Angular or even simpler VueJS